Как и куда задеплоить react-app в связке с json-server?
есть react app где использовал json server. Пробовал задеплоить на heroku, деплой проходил успешно, но при переходе на сайт по ссылке появлялось вот такое сообщение Invalid Host header. Потом попробовал задеплоить на такой сервис как render.com, проблема осталась такой же. Вот как деплоил на render - создал новый web service в build command написал npm install, а в start command прописал npm run dev, потому что в package.json у меня в скриптах стоит вот такой скрипт, который запускает и сервер и клиент часть
"dev": "concurrently "npm run server" "npm run client"".
Вот :
"server": "json-server --watch db.json --port 5000 --middlewares ./range.js",
"client": "npm start"
Пожалуйста помогите кто сталкивался с этим!

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-pJN9faoa8E, может поможет, сам пытаюсь разобраться с похожим вопросом
